# Prove that $ \inf_{A\subset B} (\inf_B f)=\inf_A f~\textrm{and}~ \inf_{A\subset B} (\sup_B f)=\sup_A f? $

Tags: real-analysis

It's probably easy, because I have found it in the book about real analysys and it was marked as "obvious". It's not for me so I am asking for help. We have continous function $f$, $B$ is an open set and $A\subset B$. Could you explain me why
$$
\inf_{A\subset B} (\inf_B f)=\inf_A f~\textrm{and}~ \inf_{A\subset B} (\sup_B f)=\sup_A f?
$$
It was written that it's due to continuity of $f$. I still can't see.

Comment: It's not clear what these identities are asserting. The right-hand sides depend on a set $A$ (as well as the function $f$). But the left-hand sides seem to depend only on $f$, not on any fixed sets.

Comment: I have found it [here](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Analysis%20I.pdf), on page 44.

Comment: It seems that the statement in question is: for any continuous function $f$ and any set $A$, prove that
$$
\inf\big\{ \inf \{ f(x)\colon x\in B \} \colon B\supset A,\, B\text{ open} \big\} = \inf\{f(x)\colon x\in A\}
$$
The inequality $\inf\big\{ \inf \{ f(x)\colon x\in B \} \colon B\supset A,\, B\text{ open} \big\} \le \inf\{f(x)\colon x\in A\}$ is clear, since $\inf \{ f(x)\colon x\in B \}$ is a lower bound for $\inf\{f(x)\colon x\in A\}$ for any set $B$ containing $A$ (regardless of whether $f$ is continuous or $B$ is open); so it's the other inequality that should use continuity.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you know how to proce the second equality?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but even after reviewing the context, which includes the conditions that $f$ (aka $g$ in the source) is $\ge 0$ with compact support, and that $A$ (aka $E$) is a Borel set, I do not see that this can be true.

Simple example: $$A = (-1,1)\\ f(x) = \begin{cases}2-|x|, & x \in [-2,2]\\ 0,& x\notin [-2,2]\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous with compact support, $A$ is a Borel set of $\Bbb R$. $B = (-3,3)$ is an open superset of $A$, and $\inf_B f = 0$, which is also the infimum of $f$ on all of $\Bbb R$. So $$\inf_{B\supset A} (\inf_B f)= 0 \\\inf_A f = 1$$

---

The other equation is true for continuous $f$. Since $A \subset B, \sup_A f \le \sup_B f$. For the other direction, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and all $a \in A$, there is a neighorhood $U_x$ of $x$ with $f(y) < f(x) + \epsilon$ for all $y \in U_x$. Let $B = \bigcup_{x\in A}U_x$, then $B$ is open, $A \subset B$ and $\sup_B f \le \sup_A f + \epsilon$. Since such a $B$ can be found for any $\epsilon > 0$, $$\inf_{B \supset A}\sup_B f \le \sup_A f$$